# Set text in uicollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a UIcollectionView and an array with some strings @[@"Item One", "Item Two", @"Item Three"];

In Tableview I would do this:

```
NSString *object = self.titlesArray[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = object;
```

But I can really not figure out how to do this for Items in UIcollectionView.

Comment: A good place to start: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12. Also Google is really helpful

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`UICollectionViewCell` doesn’t have a default cell style.
You have to create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and add a `UILabel` inside.

Answer (score 4):

`UICollectionViewCell` does not have default `textLabel` as `UITableviewCell` has, you have to create custom `UICollectionViewCell` as per your need.

You can look at [this](https://medium.com/@michaelrojas_66889/how-to-make-a-custom-collection-view-cell-in-swift-6d5783ab7c1c) tutorial how to create custom collection view cell.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.2**

I came here because of the same issue but for Swift and I fixed it using this, I hope it helps:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
    title.text = "Some random text"
    title.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 15)
    title.textAlignment = .center
    cell.contentView.addSubview(title)
    return cell
}
```

Do not forget to register the cell:

```
collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that you are creating a new label every time you dequeue a cell.  Because the collection view is a recycling view it will eventually give you a cell that you have used before but that isn't currently displayed.  This is for efficiency because it means it doesn't have to create a new cell all the time which is expensive.  This code will then add another label on top of the previous label giving you a mess.  It is probably better to create a subclass of UICollectionViewCell that has just a single text view in it.

Comment: @leafcutter you are right, I appreciate  for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Since the **iOS 14** it is possible to use `UICollectionViewListCell` class which has this text setting option. Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlistcell).

```swift
var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()

// Configure content.
content.text = "Hello"

cell.contentConfiguration = content
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question so I made a mini tutorial to do this: [How to make a simple collection view with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/3681880). The code is in Swift but the process is about the same for Objective C.

The main steps are

- Add a UICollectionView to the View Controller in the storyboard
- Add UILabel to the Collection View Cell.
- Make a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` to hold the cell Label outlet.
- Make the Collection View Cell use that class.
- Implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` and their methods in the View Controller.
- Hook up all the outlets.
- Use the strings in an array or other data source to populate the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others already posted, there is property of type `UILabel`. If you don't know about a class, always press <kbd>CMD</kbd> and select the class you work on. In the case of `UICollectionView` you would see, there is no property defined (`UICollectionViewCell` class inside the `Foundation`:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) @interface UICollectionViewCell : UICollectionReusableView

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *contentView; // add custom subviews to the cell's contentView

// Cells become highlighted when the user touches them.
// The selected state is toggled when the user lifts up from a highlighted cell.
// Override these methods to provide custom UI for a selected or highlighted state.
// The collection view may call the setters inside an animation block.
@property (nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isHighlighted) BOOL highlighted;

// The background view is a subview behind all other views.
// If selectedBackgroundView is different than backgroundView, it will be placed above the background view and animated in on selection.
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *backgroundView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *selectedBackgroundView;

@end
```